# Почему выходит ошибка в одной функции, если в другой все работает?

Tags: delphi, pascal, button

Меняю код. Вот такие конструкции были в процедуре `Form1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject)`: `ComboBox1.ItemIndex`, `StringGrid1.Cells[0,0]`, `Edit1.Text`. Я хочу разделить эту процедуру на несколько мелких, но у меня выходит ошибка, что элемент `edit1` не найден, элемент `combobox` не найден, и т.п. Я передавал `TObject` в процедуры, но все равно выходит ошибка. Что мне нужно сделать? Может что то другое передать?И вообще, почему это происходит, ведь в `BitBtn1Click` все работает?

Полный код: 
Было так:

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
i,x:real;
j:integer;
begin 
//проверка ввода
if (Edit1.Text='')or(Edit2.Text='')or(Edit3.Text='') then
MessageBox(Handle,'Enter all fields!','Error',MB_Ok+MB_ICONSTOP)
else if (ComboBox1.Text='') then
MessageBox(Handle,'Take parametr','Error',MB_Ok+MB_ICONSTOP);
//else if (StrToFloat(Edit1.Text)=StrToFloat(Edit2.Text)) then
//MessageBox(Handle,'a != b!','Error',MB_Ok+MB_ICONSTOP);

//проверка для вывода: грид или мемо
if (ComboBox1.ItemIndex=0) then begin
//вывод грида
i:=1;
StringGrid1.RowCount:=StrToInt(Edit3.Text)+2;
x:=(StrToFloat(Edit2.Text)-StrToFloat(Edit1.Text))/StrToFloat(Edit3.Text);
StringGrid1.Cells[0,0]:='№';
StringGrid1.Cells[1,0]:='x';
StringGrid1.Cells[2,0]:='Y1';
StringGrid1.Cells[3,0]:='Y2';
StringGrid1.Cells[4,0]:='Y3';
for j:= 1 to StrToInt(Edit3.Text)+2 do begin
StringGrid1.Cells[0,j]:=IntToStr(j);
StringGrid1.Cells[1,j]:=FloatToStr(i);
StringGrid1.Cells[2,j]:=Y1(i);
StringGrid1.Cells[3,j]:=Y2(i);
StringGrid1.Cells[4,j]:=Y3(i);
i:=i+x;
end;

end else if (ComboBox1.ItemIndex=1) then begin
//вывод мемо
i := 1;
x:=(StrToFloat(Edit2.Text)-StrToFloat(Edit1.Text))/StrToFloat(Edit3.Text);
Form2.Show();
Form2.Memo1.Lines[0]:='  №         x        y1        y2       y3  ';
for j:= 1 to StrToInt(Edit3.Text)+1 do begin
Form2.Memo1.Lines[j]:=FloatToStrf(j,ffFixed,6,2)+'       '+FloatToStrf(i,ffFixed,6,2)+'     '+Y1(i)+'     '+Y2(i)+'     '+Y3(i);
i:=i+x;
end; end; end;
```

Хочу чтоб стало так:

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
checkOnError(TObject);
fillArray(TObject);
end;


procedure checkOnError(Sender: TObject); begin
if (Edit1.Text='')or(Edit2.Text='')or(Edit3.Text='') then
MessageBox(Handle,'Enter all fields!','Error',MB_Ok+MB_ICONSTOP)
else if (ComboBox1.Text='') then
MessageBox(Handle,'Take parametr','Error',MB_Ok+MB_ICONSTOP)
else if (StrToFloat(Edit1.Text)=StrToFloat(Edit2.Text)) then
MessageBox(Handle,'a != b!','Error',MB_Ok+MB_ICONSTOP)
end;

procedure fillGrid(Sender: TObject);
var i,x:Real; j:ineteger;
begin
i:=1;
StringGrid1.RowCount:=StrToInt(Edit3.Text)+2;
x:=(StrToFloat(Edit2.Text)-StrToFloat(Edit1.Text))/StrToFloat(Edit3.Text);
StringGrid1.Cells[0,0]:='№';               // заполнить массив циклом через процедуру
StringGrid1.Cells[1,0]:='x';         //допереносить в функции
StringGrid1.Cells[2,0]:='Y1';
StringGrid1.Cells[3,0]:='Y2';
StringGrid1.Cells[4,0]:='Y3';
for j:= 1 to StrToInt(Edit3.Text)+2 do begin
StringGrid1.Cells[0,j]:=IntToStr(j);   //тоже самое
StringGrid1.Cells[1,j]:=FloatToStr(i);
StringGrid1.Cells[2,j]:=Y1(i);
StringGrid1.Cells[3,j]:=Y2(i);
StringGrid1.Cells[4,j]:=Y3(i);
i:=i+x;
end;
end;

procedure fillMemo(Sender: TObject);
var i, x : real;
begin
i := 1;
x:=(StrToFloat(Edit2.Text)-StrToFloat(Edit1.Text))/StrToFloat(Edit3.Text);
Form2.Show();
Form2.Memo1.Lines[0]:='  №         x        y1        y2       y3  ';
for j:= 1 to StrToInt(Edit3.Text)+1 do begin
Form2.Memo1.Lines[j]:=FloatToStrf(j,ffFixed,6,2)+'       '+FloatToStrf(i,ffFixed,6,2)+'     '+Y1(i)+'     '+Y2(i)+'     '+Y3(i);
i:=i+x;
end;
end;

procedure fillArray(Sender: TObject); begin
 if (ComboBox1.ItemIndex=0) then fillGrid(TObject);//проверка комбобокса для вывода через грид или мемо
 else if (ComboBox1.ItemIndex=1) then fillMemo(TObject);
end;
```

Comment: вы код нормально приведите, а не фрагменты непонятные. В процедуры эти (обработчики событий) передается не а-бы какой `TObject`, а объект, вызвавший это событие. Поскольку TObject является общим потомком в классовой иерархии, то он там и прописан, ибо подходит вообще к любому обработчику. Когда вы кликаете на кнопку то sender содержит ссылку на саму эту кнопку. Если у вас один обработчик привязан к нескольким кнопкам, то вы можете различать, какая из них вызвала событие.

Comment: а по существу вопроса, у вас видимо была функция клика на кнопку или еще куда. Она является членом класса формы, как и кнопка и edit, поэтому вы можете иметь доступ к этим объектам. Когда вы решили разбить функцию на части, скорее всего, вы  написали просто функции, и не вносили их в класс формы. Поэтому там ничего и не видно. Вам следует либо сделать эти функции приватными (или еще какими) методами формы1, либо передавать ссылу на self как параметр. И наихудший вариант - использовать глобальную переменную `form1`, и к ней обращаться `form1.edit1.text := ''`;

Comment: @teran добавил код

Comment: "Вам следует либо сделать эти функции приватными (или еще какими) методами формы1" - как это сделать? Добавил везде `TForm1.`,  вот так :`TForm1.checkOnError`, но теперь ошибка `undeclared identificator checkOnError`. Я так понимаю, потому что эти методы не определены в классе TFrom1?

Comment: @teran вроде как решил проблему. В var в начале объявлена переменная `TFrom1` типа `From1`. Поэтому я ко всем полям(`Edit1` и т.п.) добавил вызов из `Form1`:`TForm1.Edit1`

Comment: да, в описание класса их добавить тоже требуется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Хочу чтоб стало так:

```
procedure checkOnError(Sender: TObject); 
begin
    if (Edit1.Text='')or(Edit2.Text='')or(Edit3.Text='') then
    ....
end;

procedure fillGrid(Sender: TObject);
var i,x:Real; j:ineteger;
begin
   .....
```

Обратите внимание, что вы не просто пишите какие то функции при работу с формами. Форма это класс ООП, который имеет свойства и методы. Вы можете обращаться к этим свойствам находясь внутри класса, либо использую ссылку на экземпляр, обращаться к публичным свойствам.

Поскольку свои новые функции вы описываете как отдельные, не являющиеся членами класса `TForm1`, то и доступ к его `Edit1` и т.п. компонентам вы получить не можете.
В данном случае оптимальным будет внесение данных методов в класс формы:

```
 TForm1 = class(TForm) 
   private
     procedure FillGrid();
 end;

 .....

 procedure TForm1.FillGrid();
 begin
   ...
 end;
```

В таком случае у вас будет доступ к членам класса `Edit1` и подобным

Comment: Да,спасибо, ваш способ решения лучше моего, так и сделаю.